# Are there intellisense property of Rad Editor?

Tags: telerik, radeditor

I am using Rad Editor which is component of Telerik.

Has Rad Editor have intellisense property?

That is to say; while using rad editor when I start to write `"Stack"` word, I want to autocomplete it to "StackOverflow" or if it is possible, I want to show some options such as `"StackOver"` , `"StackUser"`.

While I am researching about it, I found and thought about below link as a solution. 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/spellchecker/defaultcs.aspx

And also if it is possible,  I have to customize the intellisense property.
That is to say, if user enters `stack`, suggest him/her `StackOverflow` and `StackUser`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not provide intellisense in that it provides active checking as you type.  The two features that provide spell checking is the RadSpell control that provides spell checking capabilities, and the browser (like Chrome) which has spell checking built in.

With the spell checker, you can customize the dictionary to include the list of words that you would want it to use.